# Does the disk property size you define in Marathon include the size of the docker image?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

In Mesos you are able to define restrictions for services according the resources (cpu, mem, disk, etc.). In Marathon this can look like:

```
{
  "id": "/grafana/demo",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 1.0,
  "mem": 256,
  "disk": 128,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "grafana/grafana:latest",
     ...
   }
 }
```

}

Now my question: Does the docker image size of `grafana/grafana:latest` count INTO the `"disk": 128,` allocation?
Or is it `"disk": 128,` + size of the docker image`grafana/grafana:latest`?

Comment: Are you sure this is a restriction or is it a scheduling requirement? The way I understood these parameters were that they are used by Mesos to make scheduling decisions. For example, if you have a node that has a disk of `256` and a service with a disk of `128`, then it could schedule 2 units of that service onto the node before the `disk` is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on configuration. [Docker containerizer does not support disk resources](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/docker/docker.cpp#L518). You can use [Posix Disk Isolator](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-containerizer/) but it only scan application sandbox so **images don't count**.